How to manually specify AWS Route53 Name Servers in Terraform?
Github Repo : https://github.com/dongkoony/BootGenie_AWS_Terraform
Hello, I am currently working on deploying AWS resources using Terraform. I am defining Route53 resources with Terraform and I am wondering if it is possible to manually specify AWS Route53 Name Servers, or if I have to use the automatically assigned Name Servers. I am using a domain purchased from a different provider. Below is a portion of my Route53 code.
resource "aws_route53_record" "ns" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id
  name    = local.domain_name
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = 172800

  records = [
    "ns-816.awsdns-38.net.",
    "ns-432.awsdns-54.com.",
    "ns-1993.awsdns-57.co.uk.",
    "ns-1298.awsdns-34.org."
  ]
}

When I apply this code using terraform apply, the specified Name Servers are not set, and arbitrary Name Servers are assigned instead. I was expecting the Name Servers I defined in the code to be used.

You have no control over the Route53 name servers that AWS assigns to your Route53 zone. You have to use the ones Amazon randomly assigns to you when you create the zone.

There is a feature called white-label name servers in Route53 which should do the trick for you:

Each Amazon Route 53 hosted zone is associated with four name servers, known collectively as a delegation set. By default, the name servers have names like ns-2048.awsdns-64.com. If you want the domain name of your name servers to be the same as the domain name of your hosted zone, for example, ns1.example.com, you can configure white-label name servers, also known as vanity name servers or private name servers.
The following steps explain how to configure one set of four white-label name servers that you can reuse for multiple domains. For example, suppose you own the domains example.com, example.org, and example.net. With these steps, you can configure white-label name servers for example.com and reuse them for example.org and example.net.

